# Node.js app architecture design parallel processing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a node.js service that has a client-facing API interacting with my database and performs business logic like any other node.js application. I am also running multiple scheduled jobs at the same time. I think I am facing some bottleneck issues. Should I create a background worker running on another process for my jobs? This way both can run in parallel and not fight for threads in the pool with high traffic.

Comment: yes split them away from your main API thread, if your not running PM2 cluster etc then your are limited to single CPU, you can use concurrently to boot them at the same time or not. further that you can use workers which then you can keep the scheduled jobs runner thin and fire off jobs for other processes to do, BullMQ etc which wont be limited to using the same CPU as the main thread

Comment: You say you think you are facing bottleneck issues. What kind? Is the application responding slowly? Is CPU usage in Node.js reaching 100%? You can quickly check whether it's the thread pool - set UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE to a huge size such as 64 and see if it helps. If not, you may be targetting the wrong thing.